# Set corner radius on an UIBezierPath which is on a xib file

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I'm working on a project that I load my searchBar from a xib file, where the searchBar consist of a UIBezierPath as to customize the background. I'm having issues with setting the cornerRadius on the xib class.For some reason I'm not getting it even though I'm setting it up in the class. My code as bellow, help would much appreciate on finding the issue.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    let image = getImageWithColor(color: UIColor.white, size: CGSize(width: 600, height: 27.5))
        self.searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)

    }
public func getImageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 20)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        path.fill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you missed clipping `path` variable. `[path addClip]`;

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way it works for me.

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
    byRoundingCorners: .allCorners,
    cornerRadius: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: anyView ?? there isnt any property in my xib class like that

Comment: You just have to provide the view on which you want to put the corner radius on @danu